# Authorization code flow instead of implicit flow with google_sign_in

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin

I am developing an flutter app where users can authenticate using Google Sign-In.
The package I use is https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in

When using the signIn() method the serverAuthCode (authorisation grant code) and the ID token are available.

It seems to me like the package is using the implicit OAuth2 flow. I cannot redeem the serverAuthCode (400 invalid_grant) afterwards myself.

I want to use the authorisation code flow (possibly with PKCE). Is this possible with the package? I like the package, because it works on all platforms, even natively on Android.